# how alert message to client when the page want refresh?

Tags: javascript

> Hi to all I'm beginner in java script I need to make some alert and
>   shown that when the page want refresh and done some work like
>   counter=0 or delete a file how can I do this by jquery and java script?
>   thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind refresh event:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   return 'Post job process not completed yet.';
 }
```

Comment: how can I when shown message if click on leave this page execute some code

Answer (score 0):

Before page load/refresh:

```
<head>
alert("hello");
</head>
```

Within body:

```
<script>
$count= 0;
while ($count < 10 ) {
$count++;
}
alert("counter increased: " + $count + " times");
</script>
```

Comment: I need alert message before refresh